Running a Java application deployed as WAR on Tomcat server
I have  a very simple Java application, all it does is write a file with the current date as the title and, a single line in the file which is also the current date. I just made this as a test:
package webfilewriter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 *
 * @author bhemrik
 */
public class WebFileWriter {

    public static final String FILE_PATH;
    
    static {
        FILE_PATH = "resources\\";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        String nowString = timestampToString(now);
        writeToFile(nowString);
    }

    private static String timestampToString(LocalDateTime now) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "yyyy-M-d__HH-mm-ss");
        return now.format(formatter);
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String nowString) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(FILE_PATH + nowString);
        writer.append(nowString);
        writer.close();
    }
    
}

I have built this simple application as a WAR file, and deployed it on my Tomcat server. N
ow obviously this has no user interface to it. No Servlets HTML pages or anything of that sort, the entry point should be the main() method, regardless the fact that it is deployed on a tomcat server.
The question is how do I tell Tomcat to run it? I don't want to implement a context listener or anything really, I dont even need it to be runable from a browser, I just want to be able to run it over the internet somehow, no ssh-ing into the server.
Isn't tomcat supposed to be providing me with this functionality? What am I missing? How can I make this work?

Well, the entry point can't be the main method, that's not how the web app works.  You might be able to implement a web app that is called by some other web app, thus avoiding the need for a user interface directly, but web servers just don't "run" code as far as I know, they do need to be called in order to load some code and run it in response to a request (HTTP GET or similar) from the network.

I guess also: "Isn't tomcat supposed to be providing me with this functionality?" Nope, it isn't.  "Read the spec" is a facetious answer but kinda what you need to do, you have to understand the circumstances that Tomcat will run code in order to design a useful app.  I don't think there's even a facility like CRON that runs jobs periodically or anything.

"I just want to be able to run it over the internet somehow, no ssh-ing into the server." You'd need a "user interface" of sorts, but you should be able to put it on a path and send an HTTP request to make it run.  If you add your application to a directory like "/MYAPP" then a request to load a page from "https://my.hostname.com/MYAPP" should load your app and start executing from the entry point.

By the way, you have omitted a vital piece of info in your string: time zone or offset. A date with time-of-day alone is ambiguous. I cannot imagine a scenario where calling LocalDateTime.now() is optimal.

Here's a tutorial on web servers https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServlets.html, note the code that starts with public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet { that's your entry point instead of main.  When they call "http://localhost:8080/helloapp/sayhello" that's where the code gets loaded and executed by the web server.

No user-interface, no users

now obviously this has no user interface to it

You need a user-interface. The very definition of the term is the mechanism by which the user can interact with a piece of software. See Wikipedia.
Having no user-interface means you have no users.

No Servlets HTML pages or anything of that sort

Apache Tomcat has two purposes:

Serve HTML, XML, JSON, text or other such content or files.
Process HTTP requests by way of Jakarta Servlet and Jakarta Pages technologies.

If you have no content and no Servlets, then you have no need for Tomcat.
See Introduction to Java Servlets at Baeldung.com.

I have a very simple Java application

You have a simple console app, which uses a command-line interface. When the class name is invoked on the command-line using the java tool, your main method is executed by the JVM.
No need for a WAR in this case; use JAR.
If you want a user to access a console app remotely from another computer, then they must utilize a remote-access technology such as ssh.

The question is how do I tell tomcat to run it?

You write a Web app rather than a console app. You write your code that abide by the Jakarta Servlet specification rather than writing a main method.

I don't want to implement a context listener

A context listener is part of Jakarta Servlet technology. A context listener runs before your Web app’s first request is processed, and after the last response is sent.
A context listener is optional in a Web app. Use one when when you need a hook into your Web app’s lifecycle. For example when you need to set up and later tear down resources that will be used as you process requests.
If you have no Servlet, then you have no need of a context listener.

What am i missing?

A user-interface is what you are missing.

How can I make this work?

You need to write code for your choice of:

Console app (command-line or Character-Oriented Windows (COW)
Desktop app (JavaFX, Swing, SWT)
Web app (Servlet, Jakarta Pages, Vaadin Flow)

You commented:

running an application with the main method as the enrty point from a remote computer over the internet is completly impossible

Yes, correct. Not without a secure connection like Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol.

What I'm trying to do is really so simple, I cannot fathom that it should be this hard.

Think about it. Do you really want any random person on the Internet to run software on your computer without authorization?
What you are asking for is exactly what operating systems, server software, and web browsers are all trying to make impossible by default.
You commented:

why it is so hard to simply interpret an http request as a call for an application to execute

That is exactly what a Jakarta Servlet does: Interpret a request coming in over HTTP, then execute some code, and finally return a response.
So get busy and write your servlet.
Example Servlet
Write your file-writing class separately. Something like the following.
Tip: Learn about NIO.2 in Java for simplified handling of files & folders.
By the way, avoid static methods generally. They are not object-oriented.
package work.basil.ex.filewriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class TimestampFileWriter
{
    private static final Path folder = Path.of ( "/Users/basil_dot_work/" );

    public Path writeToFile ( )
    {
        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Africa/Tunis" ); // Or use JVM’s current default time zone:  ZoneId.systemDefault()
        OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now ( z ).truncatedTo ( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
        String fileName =
                now
                        .toString ( )
                        .replace ( "T" , "_" )
                        .replace ( ":" , "_" )  // COLON is a delimiter in legacy macOS file system.
                        .concat ( ".txt" );  // Example: 2024-10-19_18_50_11+01_00.txt
        //System.out.println ( "fileName = " + fileName );
        Path path = folder.resolve ( fileName );
        String content = "At the tone the time will be: " + now;
        try
        {
            return Files.writeString ( path , content , StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException ( e );
        }
    }
}

Verify that class by writing a test or a main method.
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    TimestampFileWriter app = new TimestampFileWriter ( );
    Path path = app.writeToFile ( );
    System.out.println ( "path = " + path );
}


path = /Users/basil_dot_work/2024-10-19_18_57_27+01_00.txt

Write a servlet that makes use of that TimestampFileWriter class.
package work.basil.ex.filewriter;

import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Path;

@WebServlet ( name = "work.basil.ex.filewriter.FileWriterServlet", value = "/write" )
public class FileWriterServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response )
    {
        response.setContentType ( "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" ); // We are returning plain text rather than HTML. For HTML use "text/html".

        // Logic
        TimestampFileWriter app = new TimestampFileWriter ( );
        Path path =  app.writeToFile ( );

        // Report to user.
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter ( );
            out.println ( "File written. Path = " + path.toString () );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException ( e );
        }
    }
}

The url is: http://localhost:8080/FileWriterServlet/write.
The Maven POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExServlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExServlet</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>23</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Resulting in web browser:

But now you have a different security problem. Any malicious user can call your URL repeatedly to fill up your storage device with these created files.

By the way, in real work I would consider using date-time values “in UTC”, meaning an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC.

Thank you for your response sir, I guess I'm confused, but it seems to me that running an application with the main method as the enrty point from a remote computer over the internet is completly impossible. At least thats how i interpret your answer, which is crazy considering the fact, that I'm in an internship program and this is exactly what they are asking me to do.

I guess what I don't get, is why it is so hard to simply interpret an http request as a call for an application to execute. And if it really is true that tomcat cannot do that for me, is there something that can? What I'm trying to do is really so simple, I cannot fathom that it should be this hard.

@Thinchance See my additions at the bottom of the Answer.
